# How to debug template building block SDL9?

Tags: content-manager, sdl-tridion

1) I try run process TcmTemplateDebugHost.exe. This process require "serviceName" parametr. Could you tell, please, where I can see this parameter ?

2) I want to upload a new assembly (with .pdb file), but an assembly with the same name already exists on the SDL. Can I load a new assembly over an existing one using TcmUploadAssemly.exe? This is needed to upload .pdb file.

Comment: check out this link from SDL DOCS. https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-15733E98-DBE9-46A7-B339-108E3155835D

Comment: @HemKant ,thank you. I try to do the documentation, but still run into difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your first question: you are not supposed to start `TcmTemplateDebugHost.exe` yourself; it is started automatically when you run/debug a template in the Template Builder application.

In the log window of Template Builder you can see the Process ID (PID) of the `TcmTemplateDebugHost` process which was started (on the server). This allows you to attach a (remote) debugger to the process. It you then run the template once more in Template Builder, you should hit breakpoints in your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your second question: **Can I load a new assembly over an existing one using TcmUploadAssemly.exe?**

The answer is yes, you can.

You'll (hopefully, obviously!) want to make sure that the templating DLL that you're uploading is a new (or at lease the same) version of the original one and that all of the TBBs that are in the original one are also in the new one. You'll probably also want to download the existing one from the CME as a backup.

Comment: Thank You for answer. When I trying to upload existing on SDL assembly (using exactly TcmUploadAssemly), I get next exception: "Cannot generate template with name {TBB_name}, since a non-generated template is already present". Yes, I understand what this error says, but I do not want to delete the existing assembly on SDL. Why am I getting this error if SDL allows upload a new assembly on top of an existing one ?.

Comment: It sounds like one (or more) of the TBBs was created manually last time, rather than using the TcmUploadAssembly.exe approach. Given that you only need the new version of the DLL (and PDB) for debugging, you could upload it to a different folder and then re-plumb your CTs and PTs to use the new TBBs as necessary and then switch them back afterwards (or move all templates over to the new TBBs)

Comment: No need to use a different folder. The tool determines whether a tbb was created by the TcmUploadAssembly or not by the existence of a comment at the beginning of the tbb's source "...this template building block was generated...". if you wish to run the tool in the same folder, make sure to add the exact same comment in all the tbb-s by hand. You can copy the comment over from an existing tbb.